# Loaded Xib file but nothing appears

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

I just started to learn objective-C and am having issues with transitioning between loading a view (directly) to using a XIB as rootViewController.  Currently I am trying to load my xib file into a view controller object.  While it compiles without any problem, my simulator comes up blank (except for basic interface, time and battery fuel gauge).  I also made sure to set my XIB into class BNRReminderViewController and set the view and respective button/objects.  (I also imported my class BNRReminderViewController.h to my .m file)

Below is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    BNRReminderViewController *rvc = [[BNRReminderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BNRReminderViewController" bundle:appBundle];

    self.window.rootViewController = rvc;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I think what is happening is that my BNRReminderViewController.xib file is not within the mainBundle so when I init with the NSBundle object nothing loads which is why I am getting  blank screen.  I am new to objective-C so I do not really know how to deal with this as many other languages just import a .h or directly read the file. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your hypothesis about the NSBundle is correct using rjstellings code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923706/checking-if-a-nib-or-xib-file-exists).

However, if you're using at least Xcode 5.0.1, you should be able to get away with not specifying the bundle name. Additionally, since your ViewController class *appears* to have the same name as the xib, Xcode is smart enough to let you get away with not needing to specify that either.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    BNRReminderViewController *rvc = [[BNRReminderViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:rvc];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call mainBundle. It might be nil. This code might be solution:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        self.dashboardVC = [[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController" bundle:nil];

        UINavigationController * nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.dashboardVC];

        self.window.rootViewController = nc;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES; 
}
```

Otherwise, did you create app with Storyboard? If you start with Storyboard, you have to remove the line below:
[image]